# Using validation and other annotations on Lombok annotations

Tags: java, annotations, lombok

Is it possible to using other annotations on Lombok annotations?

Let's say have field Name and want to make sure it's not null when it's set using annotations.

Before Lombok

```
public class Person(){
     String name;

     @NotNull
     public void setName(String newName){
             name = newName;
     }
   }
```

After Lombok

```
public class Person(){
     @NotNull
     @Setter
     String name;
   }
```

I know it's very simple example but is something like this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From Lombok [documentation](http://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html):

> To put annotations on the generated method, you can use
>   onMethod=@__({@AnnotationsHere});

but, at the moment this is an experimental feature, You should [read more](http://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/onX.html) on this topic

Comment: Since java8 you'll get a warning that a single underscore identifier is not recommended and might be illegal in future versions. The next update of the Lombok website will recommend using a double underscore instead. That is already legal in Lombok. Full disclosure: I am one of the Project Lombok developers.

Comment: There is also `onParam=@__(...)` if you want to add validation annotations for getter parameters for example.